# What is measurement of the right angle assuming the figure is a square?

Tags: formality

Usually, the right angle is 90 degrees but in a square using the Centroid Formula creates a right angle that is quite different from the normal angle. Centroid Formula= X̄*A = ∑(Xi*Ai) or. ȳ*A = ∑(Yi*Ai) Here is the breakdown of the variables in the equation for the X-Axis centroid, X̄ = The location of the centroid in the X-Axis. A = The total area of all the shapes. Xi = The distance from the datum or reference axis to the center of the shape i. I have been searching for about 2 months and I still am stumped.

Comment: Search up centroid formula square to know what it looks like. Thank you!

Comment: Search for a math forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math,  not English.

Comment: If the angles in a four sided figure, created by the Centroid formula, are not right angles, then the four sided figure is not a square. There is definitely something wrong with your logic. It is a logical problem not a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly perhaps this will help. The definition of a right angle is 90 degrees. Although the definition gives the typical Square as an example of what a right angle is, you are obviously not talking about a typical Square. A right angle is 90 degrees - no more, no less. A right angle isn't something that exists because of the square, the square exists because of the right angle.

Comment: What does a square on a sphere look like ? Right angles ? And on the inside surface of the sphere ?